# Node.js test application (to test monitoring tool)

Tags: software-testing, node.js

I am looking for some sort of test application that would run on Node.js. This application can be something like a mock/example pet store application, banking UI, etc. The idea is to use this test application as a load so that we can test our monitoring tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a real Node application like Keystone:

- http://keystonejs.com/

It is a Node.js CMS & Web Application Platform. You can configure it however you like and stress test it to you needs.

Other CMSes:

- http://apostrophecms.org/
- https://www.totaljs.com/cms/